# Connection between ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

When connecting ArcMap with ArcGIS Online by importing the map from ArcGIS Online in ArcMap on my desktop and using 'Synchronize Local Edits with Server' everything that I edit on ArcMap is also edited online. But, when I try to add another column to my attribute table I cannot see this change in ArcGIS Online (although I do refresh and save etc). Also the other way around, when I add another column in the data of the map in ArcGIS online, I cannot see this in ArcMap.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: If you add the column in ArcGIS Online, remove the layer from ArcMap, then re-add the layer to ArcMap, does the new column show up?

Answer (score 2):

Adding new fields is considered a schema change try to overwrite the feature service after adding the new field.

here is a ESRI Blog post that covers the topic: https://community.esri.com/groups/technical-support/blog/2016/01/26/simplify-your-life-working-with-schema-changes-in-your-replicas